# Generate all string combinations from given character list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to generate all possible combinations of a given character list with a given length and exclude a few combinations. For example, if I have this list:
`chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2']`
Now I want to exclude character formations of more than 2characters in a row so that combinations like `aaaaa` or `111111` aren't possible. And I also want the output to be a given length, for example, 5 characters. Is this possible? I thought of `itertools`
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use the functions you found in `itertools`?

Comment: Lear about itertools and sets.  Do you know what a combination and a permutation is?  Learn that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools

chars = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2']

for combination in itertools.product(chars, repeat = 5):
    if all(combination.count(x) < 3 for x in combination):
        print (combination)
```

Output:

```
('c', '1', '1', '2', 'c')
('c', '1', '1', '2', '2')
('c', '1', '2', 'a', 'a')
('c', '1', '2', 'a', 'b')
('c', '1', '2', 'a', 'c')
('c', '1', '2', 'a', '1')
('c', '1', '2', 'a', '2')
('c', '1', '2', 'b', 'a')
('c', '1', '2', 'b', 'b')
('c', '1', '2', 'b', 'c')
('c', '1', '2', 'b', '1')
('c', '1', '2', 'b', '2')
('c', '1', '2', 'c', 'a')
('c', '1', '2', 'c', 'b')
('c', '1', '2', 'c', '1')
('c', '1', '2', 'c', '2')
('c', '1', '2', '1', 'a')
('c', '1', '2', '1', 'b')
('c', '1', '2', '1', 'c')
('c', '1', '2', '1', '2')
('c', '1', '2', '2', 'a')
('c', '1', '2', '2', 'b')
('c', '1', '2', '2', 'c')
('c', '1', '2', '2', '1')
('c', '2', 'a', 'a', 'b')
('c', '2', 'a', 'a', 'c')
('c', '2', 'a', 'a', '1')
('c', '2', 'a', 'a', '2')
('c', '2', 'a', 'b', 'a')
('c', '2', 'a', 'b', 'b')
('c', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c')
('c', '2', 'a', 'b', '1')
('c', '2', 'a', 'b', '2')
('c', '2', 'a', 'c', 'a')
('c', '2', 'a', 'c', 'b')
('c', '2', 'a', 'c', '1')
('c', '2', 'a', 'c', '2')
('c', '2', 'a', '1', 'a')
('c', '2', 'a', '1', 'b')
('c', '2', 'a', '1', 'c')
('c', '2', 'a', '1', '1')
('c', '2', 'a', '1', '2')
('c', '2', 'a', '2', 'a')
('c', '2', 'a', '2', 'b')
('c', '2', 'a', '2', 'c')
('c', '2', 'a', '2', '1')
('c', '2', 'b', 'a', 'a')
('c', '2', 'b', 'a', 'b')
('c', '2', 'b', 'a', 'c')
('c', '2', 'b', 'a', '1')
('c', '2', 'b', 'a', '2')
('c', '2', 'b', 'b', 'a')
('c', '2', 'b', 'b', 'c')
('c', '2', 'b', 'b', '1')
('c', '2', 'b', 'b', '2')
('c', '2', 'b', 'c', 'a')
('c', '2', 'b', 'c', 'b')
('c', '2', 'b', 'c', '1')
('c', '2', 'b', 'c', '2')
('c', '2', 'b', '1', 'a')
('c', '2', 'b', '1', 'b')
('c', '2', 'b', '1', 'c')
('c', '2', 'b', '1', '1')
('c', '2', 'b', '1', '2')
('c', '2', 'b', '2', 'a')
('c', '2', 'b', '2', 'b')
('c', '2', 'b', '2', 'c')
('c', '2', 'b', '2', '1')
('c', '2', 'c', 'a', 'a')
('c', '2', 'c', 'a', 'b')
('c', '2', 'c', 'a', '1')
('c', '2', 'c', 'a', '2')
('c', '2', 'c', 'b', 'a')
('c', '2', 'c', 'b', 'b')
('c', '2', 'c', 'b', '1')
('c', '2', 'c', 'b', '2')
etc...
```

Comment: That's not what the OP was looking for. Read the whole question.

Comment: Yes sorry. Corrected

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do combinations like ``21ccb`` or ``11abc``, am I right? If yes would that be possible to also add that?

Comment: or so how many repeat you tolerate max? I thought if did not want any

Comment: I want a max of 2 repeats of one character per output. If that's possible.

Comment: Thanks. That works great. But it will crash if the repeat is set bigger than 10. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I don't think it crashes. With 11 repeats and more, you can NOT have less than at least 3 repeats, I think that is why it seems to be stuck

Comment: I think It's because its generating combinations like ``aaaaaaa`` and then filters them out. But exactly that is my problem. I don't want it to generate those combinations because that takes time.

Comment: Which list of char did you use? The one in the example? In any case to make an exhaustive list of combinations satisfying your requirements, you need to test (if not to generate) all possibilities, that's intrinsic.